# Angular 4 - XMLHttpRequest is not defined when debugging

Tags: angular

I'm having an issue with vscode debugger. The first issue I had when I tried it was (by the way the project works just fine when I launch it without debugging):

> reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators

I saw on other posts that I have to include Reflect.js and zone.js to the angular-cli.json (yes I generated the app with angular-cli) of my project. When I did that the first error disapeared but I still got the one I mentioned in the title.

The full issue is:

> ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
>       at patchXHR (c:\Users\axileo\Documents\angular-bc\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone.js:2895:54)
>       at c:\Users\axileo\Documents\angular-bc\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone.js:2882:5
>       at Function.Zone.__load_patch (c:\Users\axileo\Documents\angular-bc\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone.js:86:33)
>       at c:\Users\axileo\Documents\angular-bc\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone.js:2880:6
>       at FUNCTION (c:\Users\axileo\Documents\angular-bc\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone.js:9:65)
>       at Object. (c:\Users\axileo\Documents\angular-bc\node_modules\zone.js\dist\zone.js:12:2)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)

Here's my angular-cli.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "angular-bc"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": ["node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js", 
      "node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Thanks